# Why is rectangular hyperbola called so?

Tags: terminology, conic-sections

Why is rectangular hyperbola called so? Is there any connection between this type of hyperbola and a rectangle?

Comment: A hyperbola has two asymptotes.  If these intersect in a *right-angle* then it can be called a *rectangular hyperbola*.  Similarly, if the angles at the four vertices of a quadrilateral are right-angles then it is a rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Henry's comment is the complete right answer so I'm posting it:

> A hyperbola has two asymptotes. If these intersect in a *right-angle* then it can be called a *rectangular hyperbola*. Similarly, if the angles at the four vertices of a quadrilateral are right-angles then it is a rectangle.

I suppose it wouldn't hurt to add that "rectangular" doesn't just mean "has something to do with rectangles". It also means "having right angles", which is why rectangles are called that.