# What has the term 'rectangular' got to do in rectangular hyperbola?

Tags: terminology, conic-sections

I recently learned about the rectangular hyperbola. But I couldn't understand why is it called so?

I have seen similar questions on the internet saying that it is because the asymptotes of this hyperbola are perpendicular to each other.

But then, what is the relation between the term 'rectangle' and the perpendicularity of the two asymptotes??

[A rectangle has got right angles only at its corners, not at the intersections of its diagonals (and if it happens so, it is a square)]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is rectangular hyperbola called so?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530439/why-is-rectangular-hyperbola-called-so)

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Yeah. I somewhat agreed to the answer in that question. I posted this question to see if there were other possible reasons, mainly because I thought it involved questions of that sort.

Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *rectangular* is from latin *angulus rectus* = straight/upright angle. That is, the adjective *rectangular* does not mean "like a plane quadrangle with four right angles (aka. rectangles)".

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it basically has got to do only with the literal meaning of the term.